"This field is required" when all fields are filled in Django(5.0.6)
So, I ran into an error during developement of a django project and someone asked the same question 5 years ago so stackoverflow won't let me ask it again.
Here's the question.
"This field is required" when all fields are filled in Django
But the answer did not fix the error for me. The current answer is out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.
view.py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import ProductForm

# Create your views here


def Upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = ProductForm()

    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return render(request, r'../templates/upload.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('home')

forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import Product


CategoryChoices = {
        ('Overwhelming', "Overwhelming"),
        ('Outrageous', "Outrageous"),
        ('Mnmlsm', "Mnmlsm"),
        ('Gothic', "Gothic")
    }

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    image1 = forms.FileField(label='select an image')
    image2 = forms.FileField(label='select an image',required=False)
    image3 = forms.FileField(label='select an image',required=False)
    image4 = forms.FileField(label='select an image',required=False)
    image5 = forms.FileField(label='select an image',required=False)
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CategoryChoices)
    price = forms.IntegerField()
    price.widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Enter Price'})
    title.widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Enter product title'})

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['title', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3','image4','image5','category','price']

upload.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content3 %}
<title>Henkan - Login</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block content1 %}
    <div class="popup">
        <h1 class="middle_align">Upload new product</h1>
        <form method="post" class="middle_align" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {% if form.errors %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <div class="alert middle_align">
                        <div class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</div>
                            {{ error }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            <div class="middle_align" style="resize: none;">{{form.title}}</div>
            <div class="middle_align">{{form.image1}}</div>
            <div class="middle_align">{{form.image2}}</div>
            <div class="middle_align">{{form.image3}}</div>
            <div class="middle_align">{{form.image4}}</div>
            <div class="middle_align">{{form.image5}}</div>
            <div class="middle_align">{{form.category}}</div>
            <div class="middle_align">{{form.price}}</div>
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="loginfill"></div>
{% endblock %}
{% block login %}<a href="{% url 'register' %}">signup</a>{% endblock %}

models.py
from django.db import models
import re

# Create your models here.

def slugify(s):
  s = s.lower().strip()
  s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s-]', '', s)
  s = re.sub(r'[\s_-]+', '-', s)
  s = re.sub(r'^-+|-+$', '', s)
  return s

class Product(models.Model):

    CategoryChoices = {
        ('Overwhelming', "Overwhelming"),
        ('Outrageous', "Outrageous"),
        ('Mnmlsm', "Mnmlsm"),
        ('Gothic', "Gothic")
    }

    title = models.TextField()
    image1 = models.FileField(upload_to = r'media/product_media',blank=True,null=True)
    image2 = models.FileField(upload_to = r'media/product_media',default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    image3 = models.FileField(upload_to = r'media/product_media',default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    image4 = models.FileField(upload_to = r'media/product_media',default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    image5 = models.FileField(upload_to = r'media/product_media',default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    url_id = slugify(str(title))
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=25,
        choices=CategoryChoices,
    )
    price = models.IntegerField()



"The current answer is out-of-date and require revision given recent changes." the answer there is correct for the question there, your problem is actually a different related one.
